# Raised center tab with newest TabLayout in android

Tags: android, github, android-tablayout

I find older github use tabhost. [github address](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Raised-Center-Tab-in-Android)

But tabhost is deprecated.

Is now can raised center tab with TabLayout?

Comment: have you done this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code,its working for me:

My XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffc916"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Android" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#da8200"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Iphone tab" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#5b89ff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Windows tab" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its my Activity file:

```
package com.example.sudiproy.tabproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("Android");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("Iphone");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("Window");
        host.addTab(spec);


    }
}
```